# Date order transformation --> patterns interfere with each other

Tags: xml, xslt

It was an issue - to **invert date format order in parent and child elements**. Original XSLT code works fine, but only when there were no other templates in the code. When i added other templates also referred to that elements - **then parent's date refuses to transform** (child element still transforming its date though).

What is better to improve\change:

- date transfromation code?
- an additional parent's template?

Here is the code.

**Part I - "When it works fine"**

**SOURCE:**

```
<root>
    <parent attr-1="1000" attr-2="abc" DateAttributeParent="10.11.2017">  
        <child attr-3="whatever" attr-4="whatever2" DateAttributeChild="09.12.2010"> </child>
    </parent>
    <parent attr-1="2222" attr-2="abc" DateAttributeParent="04.06.2016">
        <child attr-3="whatever" attr-4="whatever2" DateAttributeChild="02.06.2009"> </child>
    </parent>
</root>
```

**XSLT TRANSFORMATION**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@DateAttributeParent | @DateAttributeChild">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-after(., '.'), '.')"/>
        <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(., '.'), '.')"/>
        <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., '.')"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<root>
    <parent attr-1="1000" attr-2="abc" DateAttributeParent="2017.11.10">  
        <child attr-3="whatever" attr-4="whatever2" DateAttributeChild="2010.12.09"> </child>
    </parent>
    <parent attr-1="2222" attr-2="abc" DateAttributeParent="2016.06.04">
        <child attr-3="whatever" attr-4="whatever2" DateAttributeChild="2009.06.02"> </child>
    </parent>
</root>
```

**-------------------------------------**

**Part II - When it don't**

**SOURCE**

```
<root>
    <parent attr-1="1000" attr-2="abc" DateAttributeParent="10.11.2017">  
        <child attr-3="whatever" attr-4="whatever2" DateAttributeChild="09.12.2010"> </child>
    </parent>
    <parent attr-1="2222" attr-2="abc" DateAttributeParent="04.06.2016">
        <child attr-3="whatever" attr-4="whatever2" DateAttributeChild="02.06.2009"> </child>
    </parent>
</root>
```

**XSLT TRANSFORMATION 2**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

    <!-- identity transform -->

  <xsl:template match="@DateAttributeParent | @DateAttributeChild">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-after(., '.'), '.')"/>
      <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(., '.'), '.')"/>
      <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., '.')"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>


<!-- an addition to the original code starts here -->  

<!-- parent additional template -->  
  <xsl:template match="parent">
    <parent
     A="foo"
     B="bar" >
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*" /> <!--self-copying -->
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </parent>
  </xsl:template>

<!-- child additional template -->  

  <xsl:template match="child">
    <child D="some data">
      <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
          <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    </child>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**OUTPUT - 2**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<root>
    <parent A="foo" B="bar" attr-1="1000" attr-2="abc" DateAttributeParent="10.11.2017">  
        <child D="some data" attr-3="whatever" attr-4="whatever2" DateAttributeChild="2010.12.09" />
    </parent>
    <parent A="foo" B="bar" attr-1="2222" attr-2="abc" DateAttributeParent="04.06.2016">
        <child D="some data" attr-3="whatever" attr-4="whatever2" DateAttributeChild="2009.06.02" />
    </parent>
</root>
```

Here as you can see added some attributes (it doesn't really matter)
The important thing is that the date in the parent element didn't transform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
<xsl:apply-templates/>
```

try:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
```

Comment: UPD: here is another case when the date isn't changed (the whole question updated above with addition samples)
  <xsl:template match="child-2">
      <child-2>
   <xsl:attribute name="DateAttributeChild-2">
        <xsl:value-of select="@DateAttributeChild-2"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
  </child-2>
  </xsl:template>

Comment: ...and "<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>" don't work...

Comment: I am afraid this is too confusing. I don't know where to look. I suggest you revert your question back to the original and post a new one. Also read about [mcve].